# Flex 3 htmlText calculates height way wrong and strips span tags

Tags: actionscript, flex3, htmltext

I currently have two problems with Flex 3 htmlText.

1) When I am setting my text's htmlText:

myText.htmlText = <html text stored in my mysql database>

It calculates the height way wrong. In most cases, a ton of padding (or whitespace) is added above and below the text. I am not sure what happens, but it calculates the textHeight way higher than normally.

2) If I put <span> tags in my html, it automatically strips them out (instead of just ignoring them). I am using the span tags to be able to dynamically find certain pieces of my text. For instance:

<span class="salutation">Dear,</span> <span class="tag">[First Name]</span>

is inserted in my htmlText, and I use them to parse out the salutation and tag of my variable data.

Does anyone know of any solutions for these two issues? Any alternative ideas on how to parse out pieces of html? Any way to improve htmlText? How to correctly measure textHeight and/or remove padding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the  tag needs width and height explicitly set in order for flex to calculate the height correctly on these elements. Also, you can use:

```
invalidateSize();
validateSize();
```

To force size validation to occur, which will at times help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add these two lines before you use any XML:

   ```
   XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
   XML.prettyPrinting = false;
   ```

   This should take care of the added lines above and below your text.

   [ignoreWhitespace](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace) strips leading and trailing whitespace from your text nodes.
   [prettyPrinting](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#prettyPrinting), when set to true, formats the XML output, indenting nodes and adding newline characters to make it more readable - but also affecting text output. For example, when you have a structure like this:

   ```
   <p><span class="test">This is a test.</span></p>
   ```

   Flash will output:

   ```
   <p>
       <span class="test">
           This is a test.
       </span>
   </p>
   ```

   This leads to your TextField displaying:

   ```
   (newline)
   (newline)
   This is a test.
   (newline)
   (newline)
   ```
2. The Flash plugin will remove any HTML tags, if the `styleSheet` property isn't properly set. So in your case, it will remove the `<span>` tags and add its own `<P>` and `<FONT>` tags instead, according to any font information you've specified using `defaultTextFormat` or `setTextFormat` (try tracing htmlText after you've set it - you'll see). You have to set the TextField's `styleSheet` property to an actual StyleSheet, if you want to keep your own tags.
3. Parsing out the information you need by using HTML tags is a valid way to go.  I usually use numbered placeholders like {0} and `string.replace ()` to insert dynamic values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first part.

If I have the following code:

if( dataProvider.allowStyles ){
  mainText.htmlText = dataProvider.defaultText;
}

Where would I put the XML.ignoreWhitespace and the other line, and how would they change mainText's htmlText?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You best put them in the constructor of your main class. They change the way the Flash plugin handles the XML input: ignoreWhitespace strips leading and tailing whitespace from text nodes, prettyPrinting automatically indents and formats XML when you convert it to String, which falsifies text output in some cases.

Comment: I added that to the initializeHandler of my default application file (Editor.mxml). This is not fixing the problem I am having :(

Comment: Can you post a "real" xml example from your database? Just the structure would be fine, you can replace all readable text with Lorem ipsum.